# URL Pointing to Two Different Hosts

Tags: domain-name-system, hosting

I updated my DNS yesterday from host FatCow to host HostGator.

For 10 hours or so, the url pointed to the new host HostGator and I was able to work on my site. Last night, it on its own started pointing back to FatCow though the DNS are still HostGator in the domain registrar dashboard. If I use my iPad, the url takes me to HostGator but if I use my PC the url takes me to FatCow.

I cleared the Cache and have tried multiple browsers with no success.  Thanks for your time folks.

Comment: What was the TTL set to?

Comment: TTL is set to 14400 which should be 4 hours.  I updated 25 hours ago.  Another development is that It appears to be pointing to the old host on one network and the new host on another network.  At this point I think it's most likely propagation.  I'll update if that is the case.

Comment: There's no such thing as propagation, of course. There are, however, misconfigured DNS servers that cache for longer than the TTL. It sounds like you've run into something like that.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be DNS servers cached longer than the TTL. For anyone else running into this problem, just give it some time! If the problem persists for more than 48 hours you may have a different problem.